# Flex items do not vertically shrink when child images vertically shrink in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I realize again that this question has been asked a couple of times but no matter what answer I find, it literally does nothing.

I'm trying to do what Chrome and any other respectable browser does:

[image: Chrome rendering of the flexbox]

In IE11 however, I get this:

[image: IE version]

```
.inner-image img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
  // http://jsfiddle.net/qgybon8q/2/
  flex-shrink: 0;

  // http://jsfiddle.net/mftnbk38/4/
  //flex: 0 0 auto;
  //object-fit: scale-down;

  // https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1218984/ie11-display-flex-issue
  //flex: 1;

  // 
  //max-width: calc( 100% - 0.1px );
}
```

The fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/Kikketer/e9jb5pvh/

All of the attempts I have tried come out as a fail. In fact even when running the fiddles of other solutions, it doesn't seem to work.

- https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1218984/ie11-display-flex-issue

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you missed this article in Microsoft documentation:

- http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/891815/ie11-flexbox-items-do-not-vertically-shrink-when-child-images-vertically-shrink

From the article:

> If anyone arrives here trying to fix this maddening issue in IE11 - I suggest adding a `min-height: 1px` to the flex wrapper of your image to force IE to recalculate the size based on an image that has `height: auto` applied to it. This solved the issue and had no impact on other browsers, so I didn't need to target IE11 specifically.

So, add `min-height: 1px` to `.body`:

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e9jb5pvh/11/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
}

.head {
  background-color: rgba(200, 100, 100, 1);
}

.body {
  min-height: 1px; /* NEW (for IE11) */
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.inner-content {
  flex: 1 1 75%;
}

.inner-image {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
}

.inner-image img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.foot {
  background-color: rgba(100, 200, 100, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="head">
    <p>Header content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="inner-content">
        <p>The image to the right is normally 253px high/wide</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inner-image">
        <img src="http://connectorsdemo.azurewebsites.net/images/MSC12_Oscar_002.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foot">
    <p>Footer Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Confirmed, this technique worked!  I just had to do it several times on a couple wrapping elements in my real life structure.  Thanks!